# Using Debugger.Launch with Vmware live debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vmware

I'm trying to configure Vmware live debugging with Vmware Workstation 8 and Visual Studio 2010. Everything appears to be working except when I try to debug a service. My services have a Debugger.Launch() line in the constructor so I can attach before anything else happens. However, since there is no JIT on the guest machine, I get this error:

An unhandled Microsoft.NET Framework exception occurred in Program.exe [3464]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.

Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.

I'd like to be able to attach to services before anything else executes. Is there a way to do this without installing Visual Studio on the guest machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the Visual Studio 2010 remote debugging tools installed on the virtual machine where you want to debug the service in order to have the debugger.launch event get caught so you can debug.  I dont think you can do this without them installed.